# How to fix a sticky / squeaky clutch pedal

Tags: honda, clutch, s2000, clutch-cylinder

The clutch pedal in my 2001 Honda S2000 (applies to other cars as well) is very sticky and sometimes squeaky, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good walkthrough can be found on this [forum](http://www.s2ki.com/s2000/topic/370792-sticky-rough-squeaky-clutch-pedal/). It is summarized below:

- Remove the two bolts holding the clutch slave cylinder to the side of
  the transmisison housing.
- Remove the boot and cylinder rod from the slave cylinder.
- Check to see if the top of the cylinder rod is rough or has been worn down at all.
- If it has, polish it to a fine finish and grind down the nipple at the top if one exists.
- Clean out the cup and release fork in the slave cylinder.
- Apply high temperature grease to the cup / release fork and to the ball end of the rod.
- Reassemble the whole thing and then pump the clutch a few times to spread the grease around.

Hopefully this will be helpful for others. The original forum post from which this answer was mostly copied contains pictures if needed.

Comment: This procedure is the same one that fixed my "sticky" clutch.  I'd have to blip the engine to get it to release.  Sure enough, the slave clutch rod had a little nub worn into it.  Polishing it and adding fresh grease solved the problem